# how to prevent spring batch job from running on particular day?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

0 0 0 25 12 ?

this cron expression runs on every Christmas Day at midnight. 
I want to prevent it from running on Christmas Day.

Comment: The use case isnt quite clear for me. You have a job that is only running on a specific date and you dont want to run it on that specific date? Well then remove the task from the scheduler, delete the task, remove the cron entry etc.

Comment: @BadK I have to run this job on all days  except on Christmas. what modification needed in this  cron expression?

Answer (score 2):

since you can define cron expressions only when they should run and not when they shouldn't run, i see only two options here:

1. check the current Date within your task/job and if its Christmas Day, skip execution
2. define a / multiple cron(s) that run on every other day than Christmas
   #runs every day starting january till november
   0 0 * * 1-11 *
   #runs every day in december except at the 25th
   0 0 * 1-24,26-31 12 *